# Suspected timeout problem in PDDL (function usage)

Tags: planning, pddl

I am starting to learn PDDL and make a domain where 2 agents fight each other and simulate a fight where my hero should win and maximize it's health points. I am facing Suspected timeout plan error when trying to compile my project on http://editor.planning.domains/

My idea is to create some functions for hit points, mana or attack and use different actions/abilities to decrease the agent's health/mana when they fight each other, for that I needed to decrease the values and to set a goal where the enemy hero is killed.

I started with this simple example, this is my session:
http://editor.planning.domains/#read_session=xoSpf2es0Y

The plan I expected to get when writing this code is to get 4 melee attacks in order to kill the enemy.

Can I write something like (:goal (= (health arthas) 0)) in the problem file? I haven't seen any PDDL example write anything similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

So if it returns that error immediately, it means that there is something wrong with the PDDL (a true timeout would be around 10s).

What's happening there is that you're trying to handle a numeric-type planning problem with a non-numeric planner.

As an aside, you should share the `read_session` links to the editor sessions rather than the `edit_session` one you have (otherwise you are giving us all access to edit the one session you've shared).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What numeric planner do you recommend?

Comment: Probably popf would be the way to go. https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/planning/software/popf.html

Comment: I tried to install popf2 on my virtual machine, but when I use the ./build command i get recipe for target 'popf3-clp' faield at 31% Linking

Comment: You'll have to reach out to the authors for that one...